# 2D polynomial fit of array with NaNs in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, lmfit

I'm trying to fit a 3rd order polynomial to a 1024x1024 image array containing NaN values, and so far `lmfit` fails to return a reliable fit. I came across solutions requiring a flattening of the array and removing the NaNs, but that would remove a good fraction of my data thus leading to a bad fit. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

EDIT 1: the solution I'm looking for looks like [this](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/#simple-2-d-model-fitting) but with NaNs.

EDIT 2: this is what I have tried using `lmfit`:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model, Parameters

noedge_fits = 'fitsfile1.fits' ### 3D cube
mask_fits   = 'fitsfile2.fits' ### 2D image
mw_fits     = 'fitsfile3.fits' ### 3D cube

wholecube = fits.open(noedge_fits)
maskplane = fits.open(mask_fits)
mwcube = fits.open(mw_fits)

whole = wholecube[0].data[0]
mask  = maskplane[0].data[0]
mw    = mwcube[0].data[0]


def poly(x, y, ab0, a1, b1, ab1, a2, b2, ab2, a3, b3, ab3):
    return ab0 + a1*x + b1*y + ab1*x*y + a2*x**2 + b2*y**2 + ab2*x**2*y + ab3*x*y**2 + a3*x**3 + b3*y**3

x0, y0, z0 = whole.shape

arrx = np.arange(y0)
arry = np.arange(z0)

for k in range(x0):
    if not np.isnan(mw[k].any()):
        for i in range(y0):
            for j in range(z0):
                if not np.isnan(mask[i,j]):
                    mw[k,i,j] = np.nan

        pmodel = Model(poly, independent_vars=['x','y'])
        params = pmodel.make_params(ab=0., a1=0., b1=0., a2=0., b2=0., a3=0., b3=0.)

        result = pmodel.fit(mw[k], params, x=arrx, y=arry, nan_policy='propagate')

        print result.best_values
```

Comment: posting a minimal example of what you've tried is always recommended.  Of course, the fitting methods cannot fit NaNs (how could that ever make sense?).  Depending on the origin of your NaNs, it might be sufficient to set `nan_policy` to `omit`.

Comment: @MNewville MWE added. `nan_policy = 'omit'` in fact changes the size of the array, the fit fails.

Comment: That is not an example that I can easily reproduce.  Do you need the nested loops that test for nans?  I'm not sure what those are meant to do, but it looks like it will set a lot of values that are not nan to nan.   Why do you want to do that?    Using `nan_policy='omit'` should avoid nans in the input data, but there is no universal cure for nans  generated in the calculation.   I don't see immediately why those would occur for a polynomial model, but you might get inf...  Not sure what's going on.